# Is it possible to show files before folders in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know it's a stupid question but I would like to know if this is possible doing some configurations.

[The VSCode by default show the folders first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAa4l.png)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_file-explorer-sort-order

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Just add the following entry to your `settings.json`:

```json
"explorer.sortOrder": "filesFirst"
```

An overview of all possible settings can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).

Comment: Darn! I already have `"explorer.sortOrder": "type"`. Can't have both!

Answer (score 4):

`File` > `Preferences` > `Settings` > Search `sort order`

[image: VS Code Settings]

Answer (score 3):

If some comes across this, like me looking for the other way around. Having folders first and files second. User `"explorer.sortOrder": "foldersFirst"` in your `settings.json`.